# Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Subscription' from external module

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm facing an error in the follow code, and I'm wondering which what's done incorrectly. I'm trying to grab data from a REST API and receive this error.

**Code:**

```
    import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
    //import {POSTS} from "./mock-posts";
    import { Http, Headers,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class PostService {
      posts: any;

      // API LINK
      GET_ALL_POST : string = 'http://xxx.xxx/get_all_posts';

      constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
      }


       getAll() {
        return this.http
          .get(this.GET_ALL_POST)
          .map(res => res.json());
      }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
    [02:36:20]  Error: Error at C:/Users/nonren/Documents/Ionic/socialtag/.tmp/services/post-service.ts:18:3
    [02:36:20]  Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Observable' from external module
        "C:/Users/nonren/Documents/Ionic/socialtag/node_modules/rxjs/Observable" but cannot be named.
    [02:36:20]  ngc failed
    [02:36:20]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
    [02:36:20]  Error: Error
```

**Screencapture of above error:**
[image]

**Code I'm using to call `getAll()`:**

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
    import {PostService} from '../../services/post-service';
    import {PostPage} from '../post/post';
    import {UserPage} from '../user/user';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {
      public posts: any;

      constructor(public nav: NavController, public postService: PostService) {
        this.posts = postService.getAll();postService.getAll().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.posts = data;
        console.log(this.posts);
      }
    );
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that calls the getAll() method? That's where the error is

Comment: @FabioAntunes I already update the code that call the getAll() method

Answer (score 2):

You can't subscribe twice to an `Observable`.

If you want the caller of a method that makes an async call to be able to subscribe to the result, you need to ensure an `Observable` is returned, but if this method calls `subscribe()`, a `Subscription` is returned instead.

Change the method to use `.map()` instead of `subscribe()`. Then it will return an `Observable`.

```
getServerData() {
  return this.http.get(...).map(response => response.json()));
}
```

```
otherMethod() {
  this.service.getServiceData().subscribe(response => this.data = response);
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I already removed one subscribe but yet it still come out the error.

--Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Subscription' from external module.--

Please kindly advise..

Comment: Can you please update your question and add the code your currently have?

Comment: You still have `subscribe()` in `getAll()` (my `getServerData()` and `this.posts = postService.getAll()` should be `postService.getAll().subscribe(response => this.posts = response);`